# jquery multiselect not retaining selection after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-multiselect

I am having a problem with bootstrap multiselect control after postback. in my view, there is a dropdown like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedReportToRoles, Model.NotificationReportToRoles, new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "select-optional multiselect", @id = "ddlReportTo" })
```

and, when i select multiple items from the ddl and save it to DB, and then come back to the page, i can see only first item in my selected items only displayed as checked in the ddl. if i refresh the page it behaves as needed. ie, the ddl displays all items from the DB as selected (like 3 items selected)

my controller action is like

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return this.View(this.GenerateViewModel());
    }

    private static NotificationSettingsViewModel GenerateNotificationSettingsViewModel()
    {
        NotificationSettingsViewModel notificationSettingsViewModel = new NotificationSettingsViewModel();

    // Getting the roles from DB and assigning that to int array selectedReportToRoles

    notificationSettingsViewModel.NotificationReportToRoles = new MultiSelectList(roles, "RoleID", "RoleDescription", selectedReportToRoles);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(NotificationSettingsViewModel notificationSettingsViewModel)
    {
          // Save to Db
          return this.View(this.GenerateViewModel());
    }
```

I am using jquery version 1.8.2

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where's your post method?

Comment: i don't think it matters, because the values are posted ok, and i am able to save to DB correctly. if needed, i can post

Comment: Yes it does matters, because here when you post your model, it will loose your `DropDownList` data, so whenever it returns from POST method it must have that collection or else it will not have any value.

Comment: There is no need to provide the last parameter - your strongly binding to `selectedReportToRoles` so what ever values it contains, then those values will be selected.

Comment: It should be `return View(notificationSettingsViewModel)` in the post method (what is the point of generating a new model? - just reassign the `SelectList`)

Comment: yeah, i am using the same method for generating model for both get and post. it will assign the selectlist based on the DB values.

Comment: In the POST method, you already have the correctly bound model. Why are you trying to return a new instance of `NotificationSettingsViewModel`?

Comment: in my actual method, i am having some more parameters to that GenerateViewModel method, which is different for get and Post. So, just leave it. I dont think this is the reason for multiselect not behaving properly

Comment: Yeah, why change something that not working :)

Comment: what is the actual problem here? what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by saving the changed parameters to `TempData` and then redirecting to the Get action from my post action.

```
return this.RedirectToAction("Create");
```